# How to access files in docker volumes from the host?

Tags: docker, sh, docker-volume

I have a docker container writing log files to a name volume.

From the host I want to analyze the log files and search for given log messages. But when I access the folder which 'docker inspect VOLUMNAME' gives, I get strange behavior, which I do not understand.

e.g. following command does give empty lines as output:

```
$ sudo bash -c  "for logfile in /var/lib/docker/volumes/design-db-logs/_data/*/*; do echo ${logfile}; done"




$
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: `do echo ${logfile}` return empty strings

Comment: You're not usually supposed to directly access files in `/var/lib/docker`.  You can use a bind mount `-v ./logs:/container/path` to mount a local file into a container, if directly reading the files is an important goal.  (Log files are IME a typical use of this.)

Comment: @DavidMaze: I am aware of this is not an intended use case. Are there any drawbacks as long I only read the files in a non blocking way like grep, tail or less?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your local shell is expanding the variable expansion inside the double quotes before the loop happens.  Change the double quotes to single quotes.

That is, when you run

```
sudo bash -c "for ... ; do echo ${logfile}; done"
```

first your local shell replaces the variable reference with whatever your local environment has set for `$logfile`, probably nothing

```
sudo bash -c 'for ...; do echo ; done'
```

and then it runs that command.  If you change this to single quotes initially

```
sudo bash -c 'for ... ; do echo ${logfile}; done'
```

it will avoid this expansion.

You can see this just by putting the word `echo` at the front of the command: the shell will do its expansion, and then `echo` will print out the command that would have run.

Comment: Oh man! Had the monday off, seems to be *deferred monday syndrome* :D Thx!